# ¿Como agregar nodos a un RichTree dinamicamente en Oracle ADF?

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

Estoy tratando de agregar nodos o hijos a un árbol creado dinamicamente a partir de los datos de un procedimiento almacenado, hasta ahora con lo investigado, no logro concretar una idea clara, he logrado crear paneles dinámicos con sus hijos pero no encuentro la forma con un árbol.

Este es el código de los paneles

Panel

```
    List<UIComponent> child = getPh3().getChildren();
    RichPanelAccordion GCHeader = new RichPanelAccordion();
    GCHeader.setId("PanelMenuHeader");
    GCHeader.setStyleClass("HeaderGCMenu");
    GCHeader.setShortDesc("Menu Principal");
    GCHeader.setChildCreation("immediate");
```

Hijo panel

```
    RichShowDetailItem PBR = new RichShowDetailItem();
    PBR.setText("Nodo Hijo");
    PBR.setIcon("/Images/config_icon.png");
    PBR.setStyleClass("ChildGCMenu");
    GCHeader.getChildren().add(PBR);
```

Quiero hacer lo mismo pero con un Árbol

```
RichTree rt = new RichTree();
```

Como podría hacer los nodos del árbol dinamicamente

PD. estoy utilizando JDeveloper.

Saludos y muchas gracias.